# MYSQL: data in one column depends on another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to create a table where I have columns country and city.

If I put the country as 'USA', the city must be 'New York'. How to impose this *constraint*?

I tried but this affects data in other rows too:

```
UPDATE table1 SET city = IF(country = "USA", 'New York', '');
```

Also, if possible the constraint should be added while creating the table.

Comment: Any server side language you are using ?

Comment: i use mysql and i don't know what a server side language is

Comment: please help guys

Answer (score 0):

If we go by the logic of `updating` the table after each insert into the table, then what out need to do is :

```
UPDATE table1
SET city="new york"
WHERE country="usa";
```

Here the `WHERE` clause will take care that only tuples having `country` as `usa` are selected.

One of the best way to have the constraint would be using `CHECK`, but unfortunately `CHECK` constraints are ignored by `MySQL` as explained in a miniscule comment in the docs: [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: is there any way to impose this constraint while creating the table?

Comment: I am not sure. Let me just check. Working with other server side language may be your only option though.

Comment: btw thanks for answering. it would be of great help if you found the method to impose this constraint while creating the table

Comment: @jamesgem, yes it would. The updating logic is redundant if you try doing it every time after insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do with the table definition like this.

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name
(
   country varchar(30),
   state varchar(30),
   CONSTRAINT check_state 
   CHECK ( state =  CASE WHEN country ='usa' THEN 'new york' ELSE '' END )
        );
```

Or you can add constraint using `ADD CONSTRAINT` after  creating the table.

As per @Tim's comment, adding the code for trigger to achieve the same

```
DELIMITER |

     CREATE  TRIGGER `update_state`
     AFTER INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     SET status = CASE WHEN new.country= 'usa' THEN 'New York' else '' 
     END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: OK but I believe that no versions of MySQL currently enforce such constraints.  Instead, you'd have to get creative and maybe use a trigger.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah.. Thanks.. I added the code for trigger too